# Logic in constructor?

Tags: java

The code below is working fine but I'm wondering if there are any issues coming in object creation time.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FactorialExample {
    public FactorialExample(int n) {
        int fact=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++) {
              fact=fact*i;  
        }
        System.out.println("the factorial of a given number is::"+fact);        
    }
            public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any Integer Value:");
        int value=sc.nextInt();
        FactorialExample fe=new FactorialExample(value);

    }
}
```

Comment: Constructor is mostly used to initialize variables.

Comment: Perhaps the proper forum for this would be http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: First, your calculation will overflow int very quickly. Second, I recommend a [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) optimization. Finally, "factorail" is "factorial".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.  Probably a better fit on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you're onto the right assumption - don't use business logic in the constructor.

At most, initialize the object state.

Otherwise, things like exception handling, testing and mocking can become difficult.

In your code, you can completely avoid having a constructor, in fact:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FactorialExample {
    int solve(int n){
        int fact=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
            fact=fact*i;
        }
        return fact;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FactorialExample fe=new FactorialExample();
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter any Integer Value:");
        int value=sc.nextInt();
        int solution = fe.solve(value);
        System.out.println("tha factorail of a given number is::"+solution);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why construct an instance of an object with no state to call a computation method?

Comment: Tetsujin, you editted my answer earlier and I rejected your edit. It's very bad practise to use static contexts without good reason (factory classes, and the like). Static code is much more difficult to properly test and debug. Sure, this is a simple example, but let's not get into bad habits

Comment: could a constructor also be used to initialize events? For example in js initialize all of the clicks.

Comment: @RalphDingus js is a bit like the wild west - normal object-oriented enterprise-language principles do not always apply ;)

Answer (score 4):

Constructor should be used only to initialize your object's state / fields.
You should delegate the responsibility of other things to other methods. 
Note that a constructor is called only once i.e, whenever you create a new object. Here, in your design, you cannot calculate the factorial of a number without creating an object of `FactorialExample`. Instead, you should have a number `n` as a field in your `FactorialExample` and a separate method for calculating factorial.

Comment: >Constructor should be used only to initialize your object's state / fields.  
Why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. With a sufficiently large input, you can cause an exception in your constructor.

This is one of several reasons why you should not use a constructor to contain "business logic".

In this case, the use of a constructor to both perform a computation and perform output is quite counter to good practice:

- You have an object which contains no state and only does work in its constructor.
- You are not interacting with the object created by the constructor, partly because it has no methods or fields to interact with.
- Your constructor if considered as a method is violating the principal that a method should have a singular purpose (by both performing a computation and performing output).

Comment: On a lighter note i took him from Chapter 1 - 5 of any OOPC book

Answer (score 1):

Its a question of what you are trying to achieve together with real world problem domain in this case factorial.

If the constructor has everything then the constructor knows about many other objects.
It becomes dependent on all those objects.

When features are added:

Example: What if i want the all positions where an Employee can sit around a table. The class above will not be able to as it is too tightly dependent for creation.

So you will have to expand you domain to include overloaded constructors and soon enough you will realise it becomes unmaintainable with increasing dependencies and population of Domain specific objects.

It is best programming practise to split it up.

Service concept proposed in Domain-Driven Design. 
Best to now read about different Design patterns particularly
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns#Creational

Factories and why we use them
**problem of creating objects without specifying the exact class of object**
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Then i will suggest going forward reading about of Dependency injection and Inversion of control and why/how it decouples code.

http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: How did you get to IoC from this question?

Comment: They complement each other if you were to read the complete paragraph patiently you realise it is only mentioned to read and build understanding.. cheers..

Comment: I read your entire answer; I suggest trying to edit it to clearly address this question rather than jumping off into an immediate launch into DI/IOC and factory method.

Comment: I think it is best to leave it intact for larger audience as it answers and also leads up to further exploration. Let the community decide course before I hasten into edits :)

Answer (score 0):

In your case `fact` is a local variable inside the constructor. It is not even used outside the constructor. So in such cases constructor should not be used.