# Mocking File Endpoints in Camel

Tags: java, file, junit, apache-camel

I wish to unit test a camel route that looks as follows:

```
from("file://config")
    .process(configProcessor)
```

I've replaced the from with a direct endpoint using adviceWith and have a producer template to send a test exchange, however the body of the In exchange in the `configProcessor` is of the type File and questions like [Mocking Files in Java - Mock Contents - Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681708/mocking-files-in-java-mock-contents-mockito) recommend against trying to mock File objects.

Is it possible to pass another object that extends File but doesn't write to disk, or should I create a temporary file, or even refactor the `configProcessor` to split out the I/O from the processing?

Comment: Is your issue that when you test your code , the configProcess accepts only type "file" and your test code does not send message to "file" ?

Comment: Not quite, so the configProcessor currently only accepts type "File" and my test code currently sends a File object referencing a file on disk. I'd like to not send a reference to a file on disk. Whether that means being able to send a File object referencing a memory location or something else.

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I chose to split out the processing by making it a separate function from `process()`. It's not quite what I'd hoped for, but it works.