# How to write Junit test case for a method that reads a file and gives byte content?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to write Junit for a simple method that takes filename as input and returns the byte array as output. The difficulty I am facing is that the file will not be available while running Junit. So, how can I test this method?
I see two options:

- somehow make the file available for Junit (I am not  sure if this is possible).
- Mock/stub the behavior.

I am pasting the code of the method below:

```
public byte[] readFileAndReturnBytes(String filePath) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;
    File file = null;
    byte[] fileBytes = null;
    try
    {
        file = new File(filePath);
        is = new FileInputStream(file);
        fileBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        throw e;
    }
    finally{
        if(is != null)
        {
            is.close();
            file = null;
        }
    }
    return fileBytes;
}
```

I am using Mockito for mocking. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: you can use before/after class annotations to create/delete a small local file before/after test execution... I can write an answer showing that, but it's pretty trivial... Let me know...

Comment: As Palcente suggested: Use temporary files for testing. Have a look at JUnit's TemporaryFolder. http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html

Comment: The error here is that you should not use Junit on any of the above. When you are using an external library you should rely that its methods would behave correctly. Only mock your classes and their dependency. In the case above, you would mock the readFile... method to return an expected value using mockito.

Comment: This question seems similar to [this other one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17681708/1426891). Does it provide any insight into testing strategies with files?

Comment: I have created a Junit's TemporaryFolder Rule and it did the trick. Thank you all for the help!

Comment: please consider using this common method: Files.readAllBytes(Path path). avoid re-inventing the wheel -- you have errors in the your implementation!

Comment: I am writing unit test cases for code written by someone else. I can not change the implementation at this point. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

For me the best option here is to refactor your method so that it receives `File` not `String filePath`. In this case you can mock your file and call the method `readFileAndReturnBytes(mockedFile)`.

```
File mockedFile = mock(File.class);
testClass.readFileAndReturnBytes(mockedFile);
```

If you don't want to refactor you code, I suggest you to check [JUnit TempopratyFolder](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2010/01/20/junit-tip-use-rules-to-manage-temporary-files-and-folders/).

Comment: how does this help?!

Comment: First of all the method will have a single responsibility. This make it more testable so you don't need the file to be available during the test.

Comment: how do you expect the FileInputStream to work with a mock file?!