# How to mock Picasso in unit tests in Android?

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, mockito, picasso

I have code where Picasso library is used.

```
 @Inject
 public RegistrationPresenter(UserData userData, Picasso picasso) {
    this.userData = userData;
    this.picasso = picasso;
 }

 @Override
 public void attachView(RegistrationView view) {
    super.attachView(view);
    view.toggleKeyboardButton(false);
    view.showFirstName(userData.getFirstName());
    view.showLastName(userData.getLastName());
    view.showEmail(userData.getEmail());
    setImage();
 }

 private void setImage() {
    String url = String.format(IMAGE_URL, userData.getId());
    String tag = String.format(JPG_EXT, userData.getId());
    picasso
            .load(url)
            .tag(tag)
            .into(new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    //some actions
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                }

            });
}
```

In my presenter I provide picasso via Dagger2

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Picasso providesPicasso() {
    return Picasso.with(context);
}
```

In my tests I'm using Robolectric and Mockito, so I mock Picasso and pass it in presenter's constructor

```
@Mock
Picasso picasso;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    super.setUp();
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    mockData = new UserData();
    mockData.setFirstName("Name");
    mockData.setLastName("LastName");
    mockData.setEmail("example@gmail.com");
    mockData.setId("123456");

    File mockCacheDir = mock(File.class);
    Context mockAppContext = mock(Context.class);
    when(mockContext.getApplicationContext()).thenReturn(mockAppContext);
    when(mockContext.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir()).thenReturn(mockCacheDir);
    when(view.getContext()).thenReturn(mockContext);
    presenter = new RegistrationPresenter(mockData, picasso);
}

@Test
public void testAttachView() {
    presenter.attachView(view); //fails here
    verify(view).toggleKeyboardButton(false);
    verify(view).showFirstName(mockData.getFirstName());
    verify(view).showLastName(mockData.getLastName());
    verify(view).showEmail(mockData.getEmail());
}
```

When I run my test, it fails with exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.squareup.picasso.Utils.createDefaultCacheDir(Utils.java:257)
at com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader.<init>(OkHttpDownloader.java:45)
at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$OkHttpLoaderCreator.create(Utils.java:424)
at com.squareup.picasso.Utils.createDefaultDownloader(Utils.java:250)
at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso$Builder.build(Picasso.java:832)
at com.squareup.picasso.Picasso.with(Picasso.java:662)
```

What is proper way to mock Picasso?

Comment: Could you show us the unit test that fails?
Without seeing it I'd suspect that the problem is that you never set any behavior for your `Picasso` mock. Mocks don't use the real methods of the mocked class, so they will just return null by default.

Comment: @Pox thank you, updated

Answer (score 1):

[Don't mock `File`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17690371/7018603) Most likely your test fails because real `File` implementation is required. Instead use [TemporaryFolder](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.11/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) rule:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

@Before
public void setUp() {
  // ...
  when(mockContext.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir()).thenReturn(folder.newFolder()));
  // ...
 }
```

Comment: Now it fails with NPE here `picasso
            .load(url)
            .tag(tag)`

Comment: Can you create a new Stackoverflow question for the new NPE, please. That makes it easier for everybody to focus on that specific problem.