# Mock openInputStream read method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, azure-storage, powermockito

I am reading chunks of data from openInputStream and wanted to mock it's read method.

```
 final byte[] testFileData = { 0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x20, 0x64, 0x61, 0x74, 0x61, 0x0d, 0x0a};

 CloudBlob cloudBlob = this.getCloudBlobContainer().getBlobReferenceFromServer(blobName);

    ByteArrayOutputStream blobStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try (final InputStream inputStream =  cloudBlob.openInputStream()) {

        //Read 4MB chunks of data 
        byte[] bufferToRead = new byte[4 * 1024 *1024];
        int bytesRead = inputStream.read(bufferToRead );

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            //Add only the total number of bytes read to Bytearrayoutputstream
            blobStream.write(bufferToRead, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = inputStream.read(bufferToRead);                
        }
    } `
```

I did mock InputStream but finding difficulties mocking it's read method because it accepts the buffer as reference and copy byte array to it after reading it.

```
 @Mock
private BlobInputStream inputStream;


       // Mock
        when(cloudBlobContainer.getBlobReferenceFromServer(anyString())).thenReturn(cloudBlob);
        when(cloudBlob.openInputStream()).thenReturn(inputStream);
```

Answer (score 4):

InputStream is very difficult to mock, not least because of its three `read` overrides as well as the `readNBytes` and `readAllBytes` methods added in later Java versions. If done with Mockito, you'll need to have all of those method implementations interact with the same data, or else you'll wind up with a fragile test that may break as soon as your implementation calls different InputStream methods. If you must use a test double, you'd be better off writing a "fake", but there's no reason to do so when Java has [ByteArrayInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html) built in: You can construct your `byte[]` buffer (or write a helper method to construct one as your test needs) and substitute it for your InputStream in your test. *This should suffice for anyone who comes to this question simply asking about mocking an InputStream in general.*

```
final byte[] testFileData = {
    0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x20, 0x64, 0x61, 0x74, 0x61, 0x0d, 0x0a};
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(testFileData);
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the question about how to specifically provide a test fixture for Azure's [BlobInputStream](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/BlobInputStream.html), which is particularly tricky because [BlobInputStream has a four-arg constructor with a lot of Azure internals](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/blob/BlobInputStream.html#BlobInputStream-com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlob-com.microsoft.azure.storage.AccessCondition-com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobRequestOptions-com.microsoft.azure.storage.OperationContext-). The good news is that since 1.9.5 Mockito provides a [`delegatesTo` method in AdditionalAnswers](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/AdditionalAnswers.html#delegatesTo(java.lang.Object)) documented (with my own emphasis) as:

> An answer that directly forwards the calls to the delegate. **The delegate may or may not be of the same type as the mock.** If the type is different, a matching method needs to be found on delegate type otherwise an exception is thrown.

That means that you can simulate a BlobInputStream by creating a real ByteArrayInputStream and delegating the overridable methods to it. Unfortunately, `delegatesTo` is on AdditionalAnswers and not the Answers enum (and it requires an instance parameter anyway that you can't provide in annotations), so you'll need to construct your mock manually:

```
BlobInputStream mockInputStream = Mockito.mock(
    BlobInputStream.class,
    AdditionalAnswers.delegatesTo(byteArrayInputStream));

when(cloudBlobContainer.getBlobReferenceFromServer(anyString()))
    .thenReturn(cloudBlob);
when(cloudBlob.openInputStream()).thenReturn(mockInputStream);
```

However, if possible, this would be a good opportunity to separate your code into *the part that deals with Azure input streams* versus *your application code that works with any InputStream*. If, for example, your code takes the BlobInputStream and runs parsing or error correction code, you can factor out a method `handleInputStream(InputStream)` and pass in your own ByteArrayInputStream to test it heavily. This minimizes your need to mock a BlobInputStream, or may eliminate it entirely if you choose to only test your BlobInputStream handling as an *integration test* using a real backend. See also [Mocking Files in Java - Mock Contents - Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17681708/1426891), where Brice discusses a similar split between unit and integration tests instead of mocking a java.io.File instance.