# Access resources inside library

Tags: scala

I have a project L which is published as a library.
Inside L, there is a `resources` folder and a snippet of code that access the content.

I created a second module in L to add a main as a test, and it works.

Now when I include L into my other project, it doesnt find the folder located inside the `resources` of L.

in all the below `path` is equal to `folder_i_am_looking_for` and I generate varieties with `/$path`, `$path/`, `$path` and `/$path/`. ( I am desperate at this point )

I tried:

```scala
getClass.getClassLoader.getResource(path).getPath,
getClass.getClassLoader.getResource(path).toExternalForm,
getClass.getResource(path).getPath,
getClass.getResource(path).toExternalForm,
```

as well as

```scala
val location: URL = this.getClass.getProtectionDomain.getCodeSource.getLocation
Paths
    .get(location.toURI)
    .resolve("../classes/" + path)
    .normalize()
    .toFile
    .getAbsoluteFile
    .toString
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54142960

and for each generated path, I've tried to :

```scala
input ::
   input.split('!').last ::
   input.split("file:/").last ::
   input.split("file:").last ::
   Nil
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5346020

each time , i get path that looks like :

```scala
/path/to/projectFolder/jar:file:/path/to/library/lib_2.11-version.jar!/folder
```

I let you imagine all the variety of different path I get with all the above operations.
None of them find the directory.

I am testing all path simultaneously with `ZIO.validateFirstPar` so if you have any idea, I can add more to test.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using sbt 1.2.8?

Comment: L is. But the calling project is using 1.3.x

Comment: Did you see that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55493096/listing-files-from-resource-directory-in-sbt-1-2-8

Comment: thank you Tomer, that helped a lot ! I am now able to list the files. But how can I access the content ? I Found https://stackoverflow.com/a/17902842/3357831 but it doesnt work :/

Comment: It's a bug in sbt 1.2.8 . You need to upgrade sbt unfortunately.

Comment: i was able to fix it ! :) Thanks for all your help